# Best way to exclude any of multiple characters in a string column when filtering a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a dataframe with string and number data that I need to filter.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("101a,102a", "101b,102b,103b", "103c", "102d,103d", "101,103"),
                  Value = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
                  )
```

The supplementary characters in Name can only be a, b, c or d. I want to find the best way to filter away all data where other characters than the one provided in the filter occur, while keeping data where Name does not contain characters. When filtering with "a", I wish to remove all data that contains "b", "c" or "d", keeping the first and last data:

```
Name                Value
"101a,102a"         "2"
"101,102,103"       "6"
```

I can probably do this with if elses

```
If (char=="a") {
    df <- filter(df, (!grepl("b", Name) | !grepl("c", Name) | !grepl("d", Name))
} else if (char=="b") {
    df <- filter(df, (!grepl("a", Name) | !grepl("c", Name) | !grepl("d", Name))
} else if (char=="c") {
    df <- filter(df, (!grepl("a", Name) | !grepl("b", Name) | !grepl("d", Name))
} else if (char=="d") {
    df <- filter(df, (!grepl("a", Name) | !grepl("b", Name) | !grepl("c", Name))
}
```

But I was hoping someone could help me to something more efficient and shorter code. I'm looking for a code that essentially does this:

"remove char from 'a,b,c,d' and filter out all data where Name does not contain any the remaining chars".

I tried:

```
abcd <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
df <- filter(df, !Name %in% abcd[!abcd==char])
```

but %in% seems to use match which requires perfect match, so I tried

```
df <- filter(!grepl(paste(abcd[!abcd==char], collapse="|"),Name))
```

but I can't get the right syntax. I think I need some help creating the

```
(!grepl("a", Name) | !grepl("b", Name) | !grepl("c", Name))
```

part on the fly.

Comment: If I understand it, you want to be able to provide a letter and then select just the rows where that letter is present.  Is that right?  Will it only be one letter at a time?

Comment: Try `df %>% filter(!grepl("[bcd]", Name))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `paste` to create a regex not including the character you want. Then `filter` negating the result of `grepl`.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df <- data.frame(Name  = c("101a,102a", "101b,102b,103b", "103c", "102d,103d", "101,103"),
                 Value = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

abcd <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

char <- "a"

discard <- paste(abcd[abcd != char], collapse = "|")
filter(df, !grepl(discard, Name))
#>        Name Value
#> 1 101a,102a     2
#> 2   101,103     6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A base R way is the following.

```r
char <- "a"

discard <- paste(abcd[abcd != char], collapse = "|")
df[grep(discard, df$Name, invert = TRUE), ]
#>        Name Value
#> 1 101a,102a     2
#> 5   101,103     6
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you @Rui Barradas, a very nice solution. Also excellent to provide both with filter and base R. It is now apparent to me that my 
`df <- filter(!grepl(paste(abcd[!abcd==char], collapse="|"),Name))`
lacked the dataframe object. A typo from my part, sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

If you only ever do one letter as a time you could use a function like this.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame (Name  = c("101a,102a", "101b,102b,103b", "103c", "102d,103d", "101,103"),
                  Value = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
)


keep <- function(df, keep = c("a", "b", "c", "d")){
     df[grepl(keep, df$Name,  fixed = TRUE),]
}
```

```
> keep(df, "a")
       Name Value
1 101a,102a     2

> keep(df, "b")
            Name Value
2 101b,102b,103b     3
```

Comment: Thanks, an elegant solution, but if I just wanted to keep rows with "a" in them I would just use filter. Your solution correctly removes the rows with b, c and d, but incorrectly also the rows without any characters.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution with bringing the data in long format with `separate_rows()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Name) %>% 
  mutate(x = str_extract(Name, "[A-Za-z]"),
         Name = parse_number(Name)) %>% 
  filter(x == "a" | is.na(x)) %>% 
  mutate(Name = ifelse(!is.na(x), paste0(Name, x), Name)) %>% 
  summarise(Name = toString(Name), .by=Value)

  Value Name      
  <chr> <chr>     
1 2     101a, 102a
2 6     101, 103
```

Comment: Thank you, this is one solution! However, I find @Rui Barradas solution to be more compact. However, I am not an expert in R, so maybe your solution has benefits over the other solution.